# How to expose a service to outside Kubernetes cluster via ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm struggling to expose a service in an AWS cluster to outside and access it via a browser. Since my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69801758/3995261) haven't drawn any answers, I decided to simplify the issue in several aspects.

First, I've created a deployment which should work without any configuration. Based on [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-on-digitalocean-kubernetes-using-helm), I did

1. `kubectl create namespace tests`
2. created file `probe-service.yaml` based on `paulbouwer/hello-kubernetes:1.8` and deployed it `kubectl create -f probe-service.yaml -n tests`:

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Service
   metadata:
     name: hello-kubernetes-first
   spec:
     type: ClusterIP
     ports:
     - port: 80
       targetPort: 8080
     selector:
       app: hello-kubernetes-first
   ---
   apiVersion: apps/v1
   kind: Deployment
   metadata:
     name: hello-kubernetes-first
   spec:
     replicas: 3
     selector:
       matchLabels:
         app: hello-kubernetes-first
     template:
       metadata:
         labels:
           app: hello-kubernetes-first
       spec:
         containers:
         - name: hello-kubernetes
           image: paulbouwer/hello-kubernetes:1.8
           ports:
           - containerPort: 8080
           env:
           - name: MESSAGE
             value: Hello from the first deployment!
   ```
3. created `ingress.yaml` and applied it (`kubectl apply -f .\probes\ingress.yaml -n tests`)

   ```
   apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
   kind: Ingress
   metadata:
     name: hello-kubernetes-ingress
   spec:
     rules:
     - host: test.projectname.org
       http:
         paths:
         - pathType: Prefix
           path: "/test"
           backend:
             service:
               name: hello-kubernetes-first
               port:
                 number: 80
     - host: test2.projectname.org
       http:
         paths:
         - pathType: Prefix
           path: "/test2"
           backend:
             service:
               name: hello-kubernetes-first
               port:
                 number: 80
     ingressClassName: nginx
   ```

Second, I can see that DNS actually point to the cluster and ingress rules are applied:

- if I open `http://test.projectname.org/test` or any irrelevant path (`http://test.projectname.org/test3`), I'm shown `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`, but
- if I use "open anyway" in browser, irrelevant paths give `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` while `http://test.projectname.org/test` gives `Cannot GET /test`

Now, TLS issues aside (those deserve a separate question), why can I get `Cannot GET /test`? It looks like ingress controller (ingress-nginx) got the rules (otherwise it wouldn't descriminate paths; that's why I don't show DNS settings, although they are described in the previous question) but instead of showing the simple hello-kubernetes page at `/test` it returns this simple 404 message. **Why is that?** What could possibly go wrong? **How to debug this?**

Some debug info:

- `kubectl version --short` tells Kubernetes Client Version is v1.21.5 and Server Version is v1.20.7-eks-d88609
- `kubectl get ingress -n tests` shows that `hello-kubernetes-ingress` exists indeed, with `nginx` class, 2 expected hosts, address equal to that shown for load balancer in AWS console
- `kubectl get all -n tests` shows

  ```
  NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
  pod/hello-kubernetes-first-6f77d8ff99-gjw5d   1/1     Running   0          5h4m
  pod/hello-kubernetes-first-6f77d8ff99-ptwsn   1/1     Running   0          5h4m
  pod/hello-kubernetes-first-6f77d8ff99-x8w87   1/1     Running   0          5h4m

  NAME                             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
  service/hello-kubernetes-first   ClusterIP   10.100.18.189   <none>        80/TCP    5h4m

  NAME                                     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
  deployment.apps/hello-kubernetes-first   3/3     3            3           5h4m

  NAME                                                DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
  replicaset.apps/hello-kubernetes-first-6f77d8ff99   3         3         3       5h4m
  ```
- `ingress-nginx` was installed before me via the following chart:

  ```
  apiVersion: v2
  name: nginx
  description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
  type: application
  version: 4.0.6
  appVersion: "1.0.4"
  dependencies:
  - name: ingress-nginx
    version: 4.0.6
    repository: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
  ```

  and the values overwrites applied with the chart differ from the [original ones](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml) mostly (well, those got updated since the installation) in `extraArgs`: `default-ssl-certificate: "nginx-ingress/dragon-family-com"` is uncommneted

PS To answer Andrew, I indeed tried to setup HTTPS but it seemingly didn't help, so I haven't included what I tried into the initial question. Yet, here's what I did:

1. installed cert-manager, currently without a custom chart: `kubectl apply -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.5.4/cert-manager.yaml`
2. based on [cert-manager's tutorial](https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/dns01/route53/#creating-an-issuer-or-clusterissuer) and [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58553510/3995261) created a ClusterIssuer with the following config:

   ```
   apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
   kind: ClusterIssuer
   metadata:
     name: letsencrypt-backoffice

   spec:
     acme:
       server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
       # use https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory after everything is fixed and works
       privateKeySecretRef: # this secret will be created in the namespace of cert-manager
         name: letsencrypt-backoffice-private-key
       # email: <will be used for urgent alerts about expiration etc>

       solvers:
       # TODO: add for each domain/second-level domain/*.projectname.org
       - selector:
           dnsZones:
             - test.projectname.org
             - test2.projectname.org
         # haven't made it to work yet, so switched to the simpler to configure http01 challenge
         # dns01:
         #   route53:
         #     region: ... # that of load balancer (but we also have ...)
         #     accessKeyID: <of IAM user with access to Route53>
         #     secretAccessKeySecretRef: # created that
         #       name: route53-credentials-secret
         #       key: secret-access-key
         #     role: arn:aws:iam::645730347045:role/cert-manager
         http01:
           ingress:
             class: nginx
   ```

   and applied it via `kubectl apply -f issuer.yaml`
3. created 2 certificates in the same file and applied it again:

   ```
   ---
   apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
   kind: Certificate
   metadata:
     name: letsencrypt-certificate
   spec:
     secretName: tls-secret
     issuerRef:
       kind: ClusterIssuer
       name: letsencrypt-backoffice
     commonName: test.projectname.org
     dnsNames:
     - test.projectname.org
   ---
   apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
   kind: Certificate
   metadata:
     name: letsencrypt-certificate-2
   spec:
     secretName: tls-secret-2
     issuerRef:
       kind: ClusterIssuer
       name: letsencrypt-backoffice
     commonName: test2.projectname.org
     dnsNames:
     - test2.projectname.org
   ```
4. made sure that the certificates are issued correctly (skipping the pain part, the result is: `kubectl get certificates` shows that both certificates have `READY` = `true` and both tls secrets are created)
5. figured that my ingress is in another namespace and secrets for tls in ingress spec [can only](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2170) be referred in the same namespace (haven't tried the wildcard certificate and `--default-ssl-certificate` option yet), so for each one copied them to `tests` namespace:

   1. opened existing secret, like `kubectl edit secret tls-secret-2`, copied data and annotations
   2. created an empty (Opaque) secret in tests: `kubectl create secret generic tls-secret-2-copy -n tests`
   3. opened it (`kubectl edit secret tls-secret-2-copy -n tests`) and inserted data an annotations
6. in ingress `spec`, added the tls bit:

   ```
   tls:
   - hosts:
     - test.projectname.org
     secretName: tls-secret-copy
   - hosts:
     - test2.projectname.org
     secretName: tls-secret-2-copy
   ```
7. I hoped that this will help, but actually it made no difference (I get `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` for irrelevant paths, redirect from http to https, `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` at https and `Cannot GET /test` if I insist on getting to the page)

Comment: Hello @YakovL Previously you mentioned about usage of TLS, but I don't see it in your Ingress definition. Did you checked logs for errors in your Ingress controller? Also you can look at this example at AWS site: [How to use a Network Load Balancer with the NGINX Ingress resource in Kubernetes](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/network-load-balancer-nginx-ingress-controller-eks/)

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin well, the described behavoir was without TLS settings (those seemingly don't help, but I added the whole thing to the post in PS). Could you explain where to see the error logs of Ingress Controller? Thanks for the link, I'll check it out, too.

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin could you take a look at the separate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69964611/3995261) regarding TLS? The routing part of the issue is solved, but I haven't succeeded with https yet. I've also checked the article you suggested and tried some bits from there (ingress annotations that I didn't have; haven't tried self-signed certificates, though), but still unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I haven't figured this out [for ArgoCD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69801758/3995261) yet (edit: figured, but the solution is ArgoCD-specific), but for this test service it seems that path resolving is [the source](https://superuser.com/a/1483679/576393) of the issue. It may be not the only source (to be retested on test2 subdomain), but when I created a new subdomain in the hosted zone (test3, not used anywhere before) and pointed it via `A` entry to the load balancer (as "alias" in AWS console), and then added to the ingress a new rule with `/` path, like this:

```
  - host: test3.projectname.org
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: hello-kubernetes-first
            port:
              number: 80
```

I've finally got the hello kubernetes thing on `http://test3.projectname.org`. I have succeeded with TLS after a number of attempts/research and some help in a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69964611/3995261).

**But** I haven't succeeded with actual debugging: looking at `kubectl logs -n nginx <pod name, see kubectl get pod -n nginx>` doesn't really help understanding what path was passed to the service and is rather difficult to understand (can't even find where those IPs come from: they are not mine, LB's, cluster IP of the service; neither I understand what `tests-hello-kubernetes-first-80` stands for – it's just a concatenation of namespace, service name and port, no object has such name, including ingress):

```
192.168.14.57 - - [14/Nov/2021:12:02:58 +0000] "GET /test2 HTTP/2.0" 404 144
 "-" "<browser's user-agent header value>" 448 0.002
 [tests-hello-kubernetes-first-80] [] 192.168.49.95:8080 144 0.000 404 <some hash>
```

Any more pointers on debugging will be helpful; also suggestions regarding correct path ~rewriting for nginx-ingress are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Since you've used your own answer to complement the question, I'll kind of answer all the things you asked, while providing a divide and conquer strategy to troubleshooting kubernetes networking.

At the end I'll give you some nginx and IP answers

This is correct

```
- host: test3.projectname.org
http:
  paths:
  - pathType: Prefix
    path: "/"
    backend:
      service:
        name: hello-kubernetes-first
        port:
          number: 80
```

---

Breaking down troubleshooting with Ingress

1. DNS
2. Ingress
3. Service
4. Pod
5. Certificate

---

1.DNS

you can use the command dig to query the DNS

dig google.com
[image: dig result]

2. Ingress

the ingress controller doesn't look for the IP, it just looks for the headers

you can force a host using any tool that lets you change the headers, like curl

`curl --header 'Host: test3.projectname.com' http://123.123.123.123` (your public IP)

3. Service

you can be sure that your service is working by creating ubuntu/centos pod, using `kubectl exec -it podname -- bash` and trying to curl your service form withing the cluster

4. Pod

You're getting this

```
192.168.14.57 - - [14/Nov/2021:12:02:58 +0000] "GET /test2 HTTP/2.0" 404 144
 "-" "<browser's user-agent header value>" 448 0.002
```

This part `GET /test2` means that the request got the address from the DNS, went all the way from the internet, found your clusters, found your ingress controller, got through the service and reached your pod. Congratz! Your ingress is working!

But why is it returning 404?

The path that was passed to the service and from the service to the pod is /test2

Do you have a file called test2 that nginx can serve? Do you have an upstream config in nginx that has a test2 prefix?

That's why, you're getting a 404 from nginx, not from the ingress controller.

Those IPs are internal, remember, the internet traffic ended at the cluster border, now you're in an internal network. Here's a rough sketch of what's happening

Let's say that you're accessing it from your laptop. Your laptop has the IP 192.168.123.123, but your home has the address 7.8.9.1, so when your request hits the cluster, the cluster sees 7.8.9.1 requesting test3.projectname.com.

The cluster looks for the ingress controller, which finds a suitable configuration and passed the request down to the service, which passes the request down to the pod.

So,

```
your router can see your private IP (192.168.123.123)
Your cluster(ingress) can see your router's IP (7.8.9.1)
Your service can see the ingress's IP (192.168.?.?)
Your pod can see the service's IP (192.168.14.57)
```

It's a game of pass around.
If you want to see the public IP in your nginx logs, you need to customize it to get the X-Real-IP header, which is usually where load-balancers/ingresses/ambassador/proxies put the actual requester public IP.

Comment: Right, thanks, this is the kind of answer I was looking for. Now, you are saying *This part `GET /test2` means that [...] got through the service and reached your pod*, looks like I have a misconception here: are you saying nginx deployed by ingress-nginx is only deployed on the pod of the app itself? I though the log I see is that of some "central" nginx that routes traffic from outside to nginxes deployed on pods and they route it further to the app.

Comment: *Those IPs are internal* yes, I expected that, but thought that there will be cluster IP of the service, but again, if I got you correctly, it's not the IP of the service, but rather the IP of the.. wait, if the nginx (logs of which I'm seeing) is on the same pod as nginx, why any IP at all instead of localhost? Also, all schemes [illustrate](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/opensource/network-load-balancer-nginx-ingress-controller-eks/) that something comes to the central ingress controller, then to a service and then to a pod, is it not the traffic that comes this way?

Comment: kubernetes has its own internal network, that's the IP your seeing