# How to setup TLS correctly in Kubernetes via cert-manager?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, cert-manager

I'm trying to setup TLS for a service that's available outside a Kubernetes cluster (AWS EKS). With cert-manager, I've successfully issued a certificate and configured ingress, but I'm still getting error `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`. Here's what I have:

1. **namespace** `tests` and `hello-kubernetes` in it (both **deployment and service** have name `hello-kubernetes-first`, serivce is ClusterIP with `port` 80 and `targetPort` 8080, deployment is based on `paulbouwer/hello-kubernetes:1.8`, see details in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69888157/3995261))
2. **DNS and ingress** configured to show the service:

   ```
   apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
   kind: Ingress
   metadata:
     name: hello-kubernetes-ingress
     namespace: tests
   spec:
     ingressClassName: nginx
     rules:
     - host: test3.projectname.org
       http:
         paths:
         - path: "/"
           pathType: Prefix
           backend:
             service:
               name: hello-kubernetes-first
               port:
                 number: 80
   ```

   Without configuring TLS, I can access test3.projectname.org via http and see the service (well, it tries to redirect me to https, I see `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`, I go to insecure anyway and see the hello-kubernetes page).

   - note: I have nginx-ingress **ingress controller**; it was installed before me via the following chart:

     ```
     apiVersion: v2
     name: nginx
     description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
     type: application
     version: 4.0.6
     appVersion: "1.0.4"
     dependencies:
     - name: ingress-nginx
       version: 4.0.6
       repository: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
     ```

     and the values overwrites applied with the chart differ from the [original ones](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml) mostly in `extraArgs`: `default-ssl-certificate: "nginx-ingress/dragon-family-com"` is uncommneted
3. **cert-manager** installed via `kubectl apply -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.5.4/cert-manager.yaml`
4. **ClusterIssuer** created with the following config:

   ```
   apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
   kind: ClusterIssuer
   metadata:
     name: letsencrypt-backoffice
   spec:
     acme:
       server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
       # use https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory after everything is fixed and works
       privateKeySecretRef: # this secret is created in the namespace of cert-manager
         name: letsencrypt-backoffice-private-key
       # email: <will be used for urgent alerts about expiration etc>

       solvers:
       # TODO: add for each domain/second-level domain/*.projectname.org
       - selector:
           dnsZones:
             - test.projectname.org
             - test2.projectname.org
             - test3.projectname.org
         http01:
           ingress:
             class: nginx
   ```
5. **certificate** in the `tests` namespace. It's config is

   ```
   apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
   kind: Certificate
   metadata:
     name: letsencrypt-certificate-31
     namespace: tests
   spec:
     secretName: tls-secret-31
     issuerRef:
       kind: ClusterIssuer
       name: letsencrypt-backoffice
     commonName: test3.projectname.org
     dnsNames:
     - test3.projectname.org
   ```

Now, certificate is ready (`kubectl get certificates -n tests` tells that) and to apply it, I add this to ingress's spec:

```
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - test3.projectname.org
      secretName: tls-secret-31
```

However, when I try to open test3.projectname.org via https, it still shows me the `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` error. **What am I doing wrong? How to debug this?** I've checked up `openssl s_client -connect test3.projectname.org:443 -prexit`[*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22814663/3995261) and it shows the following chain:

```
 0 s:CN = test3.projectname.org
   i:C = US, O = (STAGING) Let's Encrypt, CN = (STAGING) Artificial Apricot R3
 1 s:C = US, O = (STAGING) Let's Encrypt, CN = (STAGING) Artificial Apricot R3
   i:C = US, O = (STAGING) Internet Security Research Group, CN = (STAGING) Pretend Pear X1
 2 s:C = US, O = (STAGING) Internet Security Research Group, CN = (STAGING) Pretend Pear X1
   i:C = US, O = (STAGING) Internet Security Research Group, CN = (STAGING) Doctored Durian Root CA X3
```

and tells, among other output

> Verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Unfortunately, I haven't found anything useful to try further, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestion from SYN, I've fixed this by

1. switching ACME server in ClusterIssuer config from `https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory` to `https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory`. The idea of the staging server seems to be: allow to debug certificate issuing (so that `kubectl get certificate [-n <namespace>]` shows that `READY` = `true`) without providing actual trusted certificates; after certificate issuing is ok, one has to switch to the main server to get production certificates.
2. Updating certificates, tls secrets and ingress configs. Well, I'm not sure if there's a way to actually update certificates; instead, I've created new ones, which created new secrets, and then updated ingress configs (just secrets' names)

Answer (score 2):

Your ClusterIssuer refers to LetsEncrypt staging issuer. Remove that setting / the default should use their production setup. As pointed out in comments: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory

Deleting the previously generated secrets or switching to new secrets should ensure your certificates would be re-generated, using the right issuer.

The staging issuer could be useful testing LetsEncrypt integration, it shouldn't be used otherwise.

Comment: oh, sounds reasonable! Although I don't understand what is the staging issuer is exactly for. Do I have to delete and re-create certificates? Updating ClusterIssuer by itself doesn't seem to make any difference

Comment: Yes, switching `https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory` to `https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory` and creating a new certificate and switching secret in ingress worked (now the service is opened via https). Would you mind if I updated your answer to be more descriptive?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your certificates didn't work, it not because you used staging server, but because you didn't specify the **tls** object within the Ingress rules.
Certbot's staging exists only for the purpose of testing, and for not "ban" you while you testing things out if you request more than 5 certificates/hour.
When you verify that everything works as expected, you can use the normal non-staging server.

**This is how it should be done:**

**Cluster Issuer object**:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: user@example.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
```

**Ingress Object**:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-kubernetes-ingress
  namespace: tests
  labels:
    app: hello-kubernetes-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - test3.projectname.org
    secretName: hello-tls
  rules:
  - host: test3.projectname.org
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: hello-kubernetes-ingress
            port: 
              number: 80
```

The certificate and the key, are stored in a secret called "hello-tls" which you didn't also specify in your initial example, hence the failure you was receiving.

Comment: *but because you didn't specify the tls object within the Ingress rules* – how so? See *to apply it, I add this to ingress's spec* in the question. Thanks for the *more than 5 certificates/hour* bit though, I haven't known the specific limitation

Comment: @YakovL to explain it simple, when you not specifying the "tls" portion in the ingress rules (which includes the hostname and the secret name), cert manager wont be triggered which means the solver wont be triggered as well. The ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID you was receiving, its because nginx controller was using it own certificates which were self-signed.
Also you don't need to create a certificate manually, since is automatically created when you specify the tls portion of the ingress object.
Now i hope things are more clear :)

Comment: again, see the question below *apply it, I add this to ingress's spec*: I did specify the "tls" portion, so that was not the problem. *you don't need to create a certificate manually* – how so? Ingress spec contains `hello-tls`, where it can come from except from the spec of `Certificate` object which is manually created. By the way, this question is not rhetorical, may be you're aware of a way to configure this without manual configuration of the certificate, but again, how cert-manager will know to create `hello-tls` for that domain? Are you saying that ingress will ask it itself?